# xquery - how to replace the value of an element of an XML with the value from a other XML

Tags: xml, xquery

I am trying to integrate two systems.
Source system uses value 'Standard' while target system accepts 'STD'.
So, I need to modify the XML payload from source system so that these kinds of translations happen.

Eg XML:

```
<Response>
 <Object>
  <ID>Test</ID>
  <Child>
   <Element1>Standard</Element1>
   <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
  </Child>
  <Child>
   <Element1>Extended</Element1>
   <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
  </Child>
  <Child>
   <Element1>Standard</Element1>
   <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
  </Child>
 </Object>
</Response>
```

Output should be :

```
<Response>
 <Object>
  <ID>Test</ID>
  <Child>
   <Element1>STD</Element1>
   <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
  </Child>
  <Child>
   <Element1>EXT</Element1>
   <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
  </Child>
  <Child>
   <Element1>STD</Element1>
   <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
  </Child1>
 </Object>
</Response>
```

Looking for an xQuery script to translate the XML as above.
Appreciate any help.

Sample XML with Translation Codes:
The XML with Target Values will be like below:

```
<Root>
    <KeyCode>
        <Key>
            <SourceKey>Standard</SourceKey>
            <DestKey>STD</DestKey>
        </Key>
        <Key>
            <SourceKey>Extended</SourceKey>
            <DestKey>EXT</DestKey>
        </Key>
        <Key>
            <SourceKey>Privileged</SourceKey>
            <DestKey>PRV</DestKey>
        </Key>
    </KeyCode>
</Root>
```

Used the below code:

```
let $keys := doc("key.xml")/Root/KeyCode

let $response := doc("test.xml")/Response

for $child in $response/Object/Child
return
<Response>
    <Object>
        {$response/Object/ID}
        <Child>
            {$keys/Key[SourceKey=$child/Element1]/DestKey}
            {$child/Element2}
        </Child>
    </Object>
</Response>
```

Getting :

```
<Response>
  <Object>
    <ID>Test</ID>
    <Child>
      <DestKey>STD</DestKey>
      <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
    </Child>
  </Object>
</Response>
<Response>
  <Object>
    <ID>Test</ID>
    <Child>
      <DestKey>EXT</DestKey>
      <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
    </Child>
  </Object>
</Response>
<Response>
  <Object>
    <ID>Test</ID>
    <Child>
      <DestKey>STD</DestKey>
      <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
    </Child>
  </Object>
</Response>
```

while I am looking for

```
<Response>
  <Object>
    <ID>Test</ID>
    <Child>
      <DestKey>STD</DestKey>
      <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
    </Child>
    <Child>
      <DestKey>EXT</DestKey>
      <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
    </Child>
    <Child>
      <DestKey>STD</DestKey>
      <Element2>Some Value</Element2>
    </Child>
  </Object>
</Response>
```

Please help advise where I am wrong

Comment: Please don't post programming assignments. Post code you have written and a question about that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the nesting was not quite right. The `Response` and `Object` constructors need to be outside the FLWOR expression, like so:

```
let $keys := doc("key.xml")/Root/KeyCode
let $response := doc("test.xml")/Response
return
<Response>
  <Object>
    {
      $response/Object/ID,
      for $child in $response/Object/Child
      return
        <Child>
          {
            $keys/Key[SourceKey=$child/Element1]/DestKey,
            $child/Element2
          }
        </Child>
    }
  </Object>
</Response>
```